# mysql replacing column of id's with names referenced in another table

Tags: mysql

i have two tables, suppliers and orders.

```
suppliers table

id  |  name
-------------
1   |  dell
2   |  lexmark
3   |  xerox


orders table

id_supplier  |  date
--------------------------
2            |  2016-01-01
2            |  2016-01-05
1            |  2016-01-06
```

Was wondering if i can make a select statement that substitutes the id_supplier by it's name (referenced on the suppliers table) so i'd end up with something like this:

```
name_supplier  |  date
--------------------------
lexmark        |  2016-01-01
lexmark        |  2016-01-05
dell           |  2016-01-06
```

Would like to know if this is the correct aproach or if i should simply insert it's name in the orders table. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple join is what you need

```
SELECT name as name_supplier, `date` FROM suppliers INNER JOIN orders on suppliers.id = orders.id_supplier
```

> Would like to know if this is the correct aproach
>   Yes definitely, it's the correct approach
>
> or if i should simply insert it's name in the orders table. 
>   nopes, you should not have repeating data like that.  Please refer: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: I would change to `SELECT name name_supplier` :)

Comment: drew? dekel? which XY link? :)

Comment: Sure :) np. Still not sure what you mean by "I've used that XY link of yours". Which XY link you refer to?

Comment: @Dekel that was a link that drew posted as a comment in one of my answers.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: oh :) got it! haha

Comment: awesome guys! thank you for the help, i couldn't ask for a more precise answer! stackoverflow is only incredible due to contributions like this!

Comment: glad to have been of help

Answer (score 1):

You can use `join` to do that:

```
Select sp.name as name_supplier, ors.date from suppliers sp join orders ors on ors=sp.id
```

Comment: Did you notice that there is already an answer with this solution from 7 minutes ago?

Comment: I opened the question started notepad and writed and post here the answer.. No i didn`t see that there is answer and after i see it i voted for him.